# Getting top 3 rows that have biggest sum of columns in `pandas.DataFrame`?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
        day1   day2   day3
Apple     40     13     98
Orange    32     45     56
Banana    56     76     87
Pineapple 12     19     12
Grape     89     45     67
```

I want to create a new `DataFrame` that will contains top 3 fruits that have biggest sum of three days.

Sum of `apple` for three days -- `151`, `orange` -- `133`, `banana` -- `219`, `Pineapple` -- `43`, `grape` -- `201`.
So the top 3 fruits is: 1)`banana`; 2)`grape`; 3)`apple`.

Here is an expected output:

```
        day1   day2   day3
Banana    56     76     87
Grape     89     45     67
Apple     40     13     98
```

**How can I do that with `pandas.DataFrame`?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's how you get the indices for the top 3 days by sum:

```
In [1]: df.sum(axis=1).order(ascending=False).head(3)
Out[1]:
Banana    219
Grape     201
Apple     151
```

And you can use that index to reference your original datset:

```
In [2]: idx = df.sum(axis=1).order(ascending=False).head(3).index

In [3]: df.ix[idx]
Out[3]:
        day1  day2  day3
Banana    56    76    87
Grape     89    45    67
Apple     40    13    98
```

**[EDIT]**

`order()` is now deprecated. `sort_values()` can be used here.

```
df.sum(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).head(3)
```

Comment: Note: this doesn't handle duplicates labels in the index, but to do so is less elegant imo. Note there is an issue for nlargest in 0.14.

Comment: .order() is now deprecated, so pandas will print warnings. The alternative is to use sort_values which can safely be replaced for this use-case.